# How to add Strings to a LinkedHashSet?

Tags: java, generics, hashset, linkedhashset

```
LinkedHashSet lHs = new LinkedHashSet();
lHs.add("Beta");
```

When compiling the above (tutorialspoint uses a similar approach), I get the error:

> The method add(String) is undefined for the type LinkedHashSet

And if it's generic (which I think it is from its class declaration):

```
LinkedHashSet<String> lHs = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
lHs.add("Beta");
```

then I get the error:

> The type LinkedHashSet is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

From the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), it seems that LinkedHashSet should work with the generic version because it extends HashSet, and HashSet works with add().

**How do I add a String to a LinkedHashSet?** Do I need to make my own overloaded add() method to include Strings?

[See whole program here](https://pastebin.com/UJwifHv2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your code:

```
class LinkedHashSet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //LinkedHashSet<String> lHs = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        LinkedHashSet lHs = new LinkedHashSet();

        lHs.add("Beta");
        lHs.add("Alpha");
        lHs.add("Eta");
        lHs.add("Gamma");
        lHs.add("Epsilon");
        lHs.add("Omega");

        System.out.println(lHs);
    }
}
```

The class name containing your code is named `LinkedHashSet`, which hides `java.util.LinkedHashSet`. Your class has no `add` method, and no generic type parameter. Hence the errors.

You should rename it. And you should use the generic declaration (`LinkedHashSet<String> lHs = new LinkedHashSet<String>();` or `Set<String> lHs = new LinkedHashSet<>();`).

Comment: Thanks. How come I should use the generic version? Is it to ensure type safety - make sure that the correct data type is entered?

Comment: @knjk04 Yes. You should never use raw types.